# SQLite finding which table a data from user input is located

Tags: sqlite, database-design

Currently, I am working on building a GUI program that stores and retrieves data of peoples from an SQLite database using Python. I run into a problem with the search functionality. The database has 4 tables: Person, Children, Teens, and Adults (for different age groups). Person is the "parent" table that only contains the name and date of birth while the remaining tables have the rest of the information and have name as a foreign key that references Person. I am trying to implement what I learned in my database class about normal forms.

My problem is when the user inputs the name they want to obtain information on, how can you find which table the name that was inputted is from? I want to give the option for the user to select what column names they want to be shown in the result. Each of the three tables has a different amount of column names. My first thought is to do a brute force method of querying each table and figuring out which table has the name, but I know that approach is very inefficient and very slow. I am new in using SQLite. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Person Table only has two columns, name and birth date, You can extract his age from it. And depending on what ranges of Age, You can decide which Table to search.

Comment: You're right. I didn't even think about that. Thank you very much. You are amazing